# Cannot read image successfully in tensorflow

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to read the jpeg images into batch for image recognation. The images are in the /Image_p/ file and the image name are listed in the label.csv file, which are presented like 14634_right.

My question is **how to fix my code to read the images into batch successfully?**
    To be more spcific, I don't know whether should I write a `for` loop and where to implement it.

For the original code, I got the error message on `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` function:

```
ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), TensorShape([])]
```

My origin code:

```
# filepath
csv_filepath = r'C:\Users\Jeffy\OneDrive\Course\NMDA\retinaProject\label.csv'

# image parameter
pic_num = 100
pic_height = 64
pic_width = 64
batch_size = 10

# =============================================================================
# import library
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# =============================================================================
# read csv data
csv = np.loadtxt(open(csv_filepath,"rb"), delimiter=",", dtype='str')
pic_filename = ["" for x in range(pic_num)]

for i in range(pic_num):
    pic_filename[i] = eval(csv[i,0]).decode("utf-8") +'.jpeg'

# read the data into batch
for i in range(pic_num):
    # read and decode the image
    image_contents = tf.read_file('Image_p/' + eval(csv[i,0]).decode("utf-8") +'.jpeg')
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)
    image = tf.to_float(image)

    # Generate batch
    batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, float(eval(csv[i,1]))], 
                                   batch_size = batch_size, 
                                    num_threads = 1,

                                    capacity = batch_size * 100, 
                                    min_after_dequeue = batch_size * 10)


with tf.Session() as sess:    
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    image_tensor = sess.run([batch])
    print(batch)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Plus, I have also writen a new file which can read a image successfully (thanks for the help from martianwars). 
My test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
# read and decode the image
image_contents = tf.read_file('Image_p/11247_left.jpeg')
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_contents, channels=3)

with tf.Session() as sess:   
    img = sess.run(image)
    print(img)
```

Comment: Did the answer help you @Jeffy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` will have a `(?, ?, 3)` shape since it's not yet been read, but you have specified the channel in the `decode_jpeg()` function. Try to print this instead,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:   
    img = sess.run(image)
    print(img)
```

Comment: thank you very much. Would you help me fix the first origin code? frankly speaking, I don't know whether and where should I write the for loop and the `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`.  I'm quite a beginner in ML, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you try to run `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` *after* you have done `sess.run(image)`?

Comment: thx a lot! It seems works, but I still have some problems in matching image with its label =(